# How to manipulate a dictionary by its values

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with being able to manipulate the values of a dictionary. In the case of my code here, I can't seem to get the dictionary to show anything, let alone assign the keys of menu to specialMenu if any of the values are $20 or more.

Can Someone help by showing and explaining the syntax for the dictionary only to show any values of $20 or more and how to assign them to specialMenu dictionary?

The information on the txt file I read in is as follows:

```
Ham and Egg Sandwich $15.75
Bacon and Cheese Plate $9.50
Tuna Salad $12.30
Ceasar Salad $8.00
Beef Soup $9.00
Spicy Beef Barbeque $20.00
Pork Barbeque $18.00
Oven Chicken Barbeque $15.00
Pulled Beef Barbeque Burger $25.00
House Salad $5.00
Turkey Burger $17.00
Mushroom Swiss Burger $15.00
Full Rack of Ribs $22.50
Half Rack of Ribs $11.25
Cheese Cake $9.50
House Tea $3.00
Champagne $20.00
Pellegrino $5.40
White Wine $7.50
Red Wine $11.00
```

Here is my  code :

```
menu = {}
specailMenu = {}
 

def getMenu():

    """Displays the menu.txt file"""
    print("Here is our current menu: \n")
    inputFile = open("standardMenu.txt", 'r')
    print("{:<30} {:<10}".format("Item", "Price"))
    for line in inputFile:
        itemInfo = line.split("$")
        itemName = itemInfo[0].strip()
        itemPrice = itemInfo[1].strip()
        menu[itemName] = itemPrice
        print("{:<30} ${:<10.2f}".format(itemName, float(itemPrice)))
    print("\n")
    inputFile.close()
    getSpecailMenu(menu)
    return
 

def getSpecailMenu(menu):

    """Takes Menu items $20 or more and adds them to Specail Menu"""
    #sortedByValue = {k:v for k,v in sorted(menu.items(),key = lambda v:v[1])}
    for k,v in menu.items():
        if v == 20:
             specailMenu.append(k)
    print(specailMenu)
    """viewMenu(specailMenu)
    print("The total average cost of the Specail Menu is ",mean(specailMenu))"""
    return
 

def viewMenu(specaiMenu):

     """Displays the Menu"""
     print("Here is our Specail Menu")
     print("{:<30} {:<10}".format("Item", "Price"))
     for x, y in specailMenu.items():
        print("{:<30} ${:<10.2f}".format(x, float(y)))
 
def mean(x):
    """find the average of the menu cost"""
    total = 0
    for count in x:
        total += count
    return total / len(x)
 

def ext():

    """exits the program"""
    input("Hit any button to exit: ")
    exit
    return
 

def main():

    """The main function for this script"""
    getMenu()
    ext()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You don't convert the price to a numeric type. You'd also want to do `if v >= 20`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `if v == 20:`, what do you expect that to mean? What do you expect `v` to look like? In particular, what do you expect the *type* of `v` to be? There is nothing wrong with the logic to build the dictionaries; the problem is entirely in the logic that decides what belongs.

Comment: By the way: it's spelled `special`.

Comment: @ddejohn, how would I convert price to a numeric type? Edit nvm found out how

Comment: You already do it in your print statement. But you're only printing that numeric value, which is pointless. Do `menu[itemName] = float(itemPrice)`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel not exactly. The logic for building the `specialMenu` dict is completely incorrect. It never raises an exception though precisely because of the type gaff OP made with the item price.

Comment: @Balexander013 were you helped by any of the answers provided? If so, please accept one so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can iterate over the key-value pairs and just print the ones you're interested in like so (`somedict` is you dictionary):

```py
for key, value in somedict.items():
    if value >= 20:
        print(value)
```

if you want a new dictionary with only the items you're interested in, you can adapt:

```py
newdict = dict()
for key, value in somedict.items():
    if value >= 20:
        newdict[key] = value
```

you could also use dictionary comprehension, which achieves the same in a more compact way:

```py
newdict = {key: value for key, value in somedict.items() if value >= 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, nobody has pointed out the actual problem with your code: the item prices are strings, to which you then attempt to compare with `== 20` which will always be `False`. If it *had* ever been `True`, you'd have gotten an `AttributeError` because dictionaries don't have an `.append()` method.

The fix is two-fold. First, convert the item price to a numeric value:

```py
def getMenu():
    ...
    for line in inputFile:
        ...
        menu[itemName] = float(itemPrice)
    ...
```

Then, fix the special menu function:

```
# specailMenu should be spelled specialMenu
def getSpecialMenu(menu):
    for k, v in menu.items():
        if v >= 20:  # need >= comparator
             specialMenu[k] = v
    ...
```

Now, on to some Python stuff:

1. Functions and variables are conventionally written using `snake_case` -- that is, lowercased words separated with underscores
2. You shouldn't use global variables for your dictionaries -- generally you should avoid using global variables entirely unless you have a very good reason and know what you're doing
3. Use a `with` block to open and close your file
4. Write a separate `menu_printer()` function that will take any dictionary menu and print it
5. The "main" function for the script should be contained within the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, there is no need for a separate `main()` function, and indeed, later on when you start importing your own modules, you will not want a function like that present in the imported objects

Here's how your code would look with these changes in mind:

```py
# `with` automatically closes the file when done
def get_menu(file_path: str) -> dict:
    menu = {}
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            item, price = line.strip().split(" $")
            menu[item] = float(price)
    return menu


def get_special_menu(menu: dict) -> dict:
    special_menu = {}
    for item, price in menu.items():
        if price >= 20:
            special_menu[item] = price
    return special_menu


def menu_printer(menu: dict, header: str):
    print(header)
    for item, price in menu.items():
        print("{:<30} ${:<10.2f}".format(item, price))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu = get_menu("standardMenu.txt")
    menu_printer(menu, "Main menu")

    special_menu = get_special_menu(menu)
    menu_printer(special_menu, "Special menu")
```

Answer (score -1):

I read: `specailMenu = {}` and then I read `specailMenu.append(k)` in your `getSpecailMenu` definition. This should throw an exception. Dictionaries cannot be appended to in Python:

```
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> myDic = {}
>>> myDic.append("Hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> exit()
```

Also, did you mean to spell special instead of specail?

Not the most pythonic way, but it'll help you move along:

To iterate over all keys of a dictionary and print the values:

```py
myDic = {0: "My", 1: "cool", 2: "dictionary."}

for everyKey in myDic.keys():
    print(myDic[everyKey])
```

This will allow you to access each `key:value` pair in your dictionary.
To either overwrite or assign a new `key:value` pair into a dictionary:

```py
myDic = {}
myDic[0] = "My" # Add a new key:value pair
myDic[1] = "cool" # Add a new key:value pair
myDic[0] = "dictionary." # Overwrite the value already assigned to key 0
```

EDIT1:
Remember that keys can only be immutable objects.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: "Remember that keys and values can be of any type." -- careful, this isn't true of keys.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
I stand corrected, in 5.5 we can read that dictionary keys may only be immutable objects. I ignorantly said any type, having never used a mutable object as a key for a dictionary.